# Implementing decorators in python yapsy plugin manager

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

1. I have made a few plugins using the python plugin manager module
   called yapsy.
2. I have also implemented a decorators on each plugins to display time they take to run by decorating the run functions of each plugins with the decorators

**This is how yapsy plugin runs**

```
manager = ConfigurablePluginManager()
manager.setConfigParser(config, write_config)
manager.setPluginInfoExtension("info")
manager.setPluginPlaces(['plugins/'])
manager.collectPlugins()
try:
   for plugininfo in manager.getAllPlugins():
      manager.activatePluginByName(plugininfo.name, category_name='Default', save_state=True)

      plugininfo.plugin_object.run(cons.MAIN_CONFIG, outputpath, finallogs, plugininfo.name, args.inventory)
                    print('\n')
        except Exception as error:
            print("Plugin Configuration Error", error)
```

Description:

> With the ConfigurablePluginManager instance the run method of all the plugins are getting
>   called which has the decorated decorated to display the time it takes

**Requirements:**
Is there a way to implement decorators in yapsy so that I dont have to implement the decorators on each and every run function of the plugins individually.